# What's the name of the org. compound: Ar-C(O)CH3

Tags: nomenclature

What's the name of this compound?

*I know that Ar-C=O- is the Benzoyl group

[image: img]

Comment: It is acetophenone. The Ar-C=O is phenone group.https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/phenone

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the comment
It's Acetophenone

Comment: The name acetophenone is correct; however, according to current IUPAC recommendations, it is retained only for general nomenclature. The preferred IUPAC name is the systematically constructed substitutive name 1-phenylethan-1-one.